# Why TS show error at console.log(add(b))?

Tags: typescript

Example code:

```
let a: string | undefined;

function echo<T>(a: T): T {
    return a;
}

function add(a: string): string {
    return `${a}1`;
}

let b = echo(a);
const c = echo(a);

if (!b || !c) {
    return;
}

const why = function () {
    console.log(add(b)); // Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'
    console.log(add(c));
};
```

Why `const` doesn't have this error? `b` and `c` basically the same, and code do check both variable weather they are false value. I look up some documentation, didn't find explanation.

Comment: your `add` function only accepts an argument of type `string`. Your variable `a` is of type `string | undefined` so TypeScript throws an error to tell you those don't match.

Comment: @Andreas only if you remove the `return` in the `if`, then it complains. See here: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/DYUwLgBAhgXBDOYBOBLAdgcwgHwgVzQBMQAzdEQgbgChqSCBjMFAezQhAYAsWAeAFQB8AClgR+ASjj8IAb2oRFEJODxJ2UGgF9a9NE1YbChUXESpMUhMnRZ5S5avUQABgBJZULQEYX23YzMbBAAtlDowhJyCkqgkABGEAC8HNwsohI0DgxsiBAMyak8GTQxiigkEMIAhInYuNUMUfZKKmBqaFlKOmX5uZAA7lwAnoV6BsGR0Q7ZuSygAHTALBiixsLxEpkQAPQ7EACCSBh4ISBokCyVYMMADiAQAOTmtjj4RKTkhI8QKPAQaBYkCg8HgKAwaCg8VAEDALAgtygSCgZzAICQECusLuD2eNkwjwW-BxTwIxDIaAoPz+AKB0FB4Mh0IecOx9yeLwJvVmaHg8xASxWaxMTUyvS02iAA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `c` it works ok, because this part:

```
if (!b || !c) {
    return;
}
```

ensures that `c` is a string (since it would return on undefined). Additionally `c` can't be changed after this `if` block, because it's a `const`.

On the other hand, `b` is defined as a `let` and TS compiler can't ensure that it wasn't changed after the `if - return` block and before the `why` function is invoked. So it still can be either string or undefined at any stage.

Comment: I initially missed that `console.log(add(b));` was inside a function. Now it makes sense - `b` could be a truthy string as would `c` be but *after* the `if` is bypassed `b` could theoretically change at any point before `why()` is called. So, at at the time of calling `why`, there is no guarantee that `b` won't be `undefined`. While `c` will most definitely be truthy at that point, as it won't change.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks for reply, so is this means TS won't check wether  ```let``` variable were reassigned after  ```if```. I mean ideally, TS sees ```b``` won't be changed after ```if```, no error at ```console.log(add(b))```, otherwise show error

Answer (score 0):

typeof a is string | undefined, your echo function is using generics, therefore your b will be the same type as a --> string | undefined.

Now your function add only accepts arguments of type string, either do a undefined check or modify the function so that it works with an argument of type undefined

Answer (score -1):

Because const assignment by default is compile type after the can't be assigned so const has type by default and on the other hand let variables can't have type so they are always totally depends upon run time...
You can solve this problem by giving type to your let varibale everything will be fine.

Comment: "*let variables can't have type so they are always totally depends upon run time.*" This is wrong. `let` variables can most definitely have a persistent type in TS - if you have `let x: string` then the compiler will stop you assigning `x = 42`, even if that's valid for JS.